# if in list return object in list

Tags: python, list, unique

I was wondering if there was a pythonic way to do the following:

```
if check_object in list_of_objects:
    return #the object from list
else:
    return check_object
```

I could iterate over the list to find the matching object if it was found inside the list but that seems like overkill, is there a more pythonic way to do this?

Comment: If `check_object` is in the list, then returning the object from the list is equivalent to returning `check_object` anyway.  Why don't you just return `check_object` no matter what?

Comment: say the two objects are part of an inventory and you only want one instance of each object, the objects may be considered equal by name but have other different attributes so you want to retur the object you already have not a fresh one

Comment: also if check object was a memory hog i wouldn't want two equal versions existing at the same time, id rather let one get garbage collected and just use the other

Comment: In general if you find yourself doing this kind of thing a lot then you're not giving your class the right definition of equality.

Comment: @BrenBarn let's say the `list_of_objects` is a list of lists then in that case the objects to be matched might have the same value but their `id()` are different.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'c']
if 'b' in x:
    print x[x.index('b')]
else:
    print 'not found'
```

You can also return object itself. Work with python >= 2.4:

```
print 'a' in x and 'a' or 'not found'
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this would work ...

```
try:
    idx = list_of_objects.index(check_object)
    return list_of_objects[idx]
except ValueError:
    return check_object
```

This has the advantage that it only needs to look for the object in the list once (instead of twice) as some of the other solutions suggest.  Also, many people consider it more pythonic to "ask for forgiveness" instead of "looking before leaping".  (EAFP vs LBYL)

Answer (score 0):

"say the two objects are part of an inventory and you only want one instance of each object, the objects may be considered equal by name but have other different attributes so you want to retur the object you already have not a fresh one"

What you're doing here won't achieve that, though. You're looking for the existence of an object in a list, and then returning that same object. *They cannot have different attributes* as you're *testing for identity* and not equality.

It might be better for you to replace `list_of_objects` with `dict_of_objects` and do lookup based on IDs or names of the objects:

```
# Example class with identifier
class ExampleObject(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

example1 = ExampleObject('one')

# Object Registry: just convenience methods on a dict for easier lookup
class ObjectRegistry(dict):
    def register(self, object):
        self[object.name] = object

    def lookup(self, object):
        name = getattr(object, 'name', object)
        return self.get(name, object)

# Create the registry and add some objects
dict_of_objects = ObjectRegistry()
dict_of_objects.register(example1)

# Looking up the existing object will return itself
assert dict_of_objects.lookup(example1) is example1

# Looking up a new object with the same name will return the original
example1too = ExampleObject('one')
assert dict_of_objects.lookup(example1too) is example1
```

So checking for existence in a list will always return the *same* item as the one that matched, whereas comparing keys in a dictionary allows you to retrieve a *different* item.

Answer (score -2):

```
return check_object if check_object in list_of_objects else None
```

Comment: This doesn't do the lookup, which is required.